# Rendering issues when drawing text on low-res Magick.Net image

Tags: c#, magicknet

I'm building a tool which renders text on a low-resolution image (it targets a low-resolution sign).

We're using Magick.NET, so rendering text is quite easy:

```
using ImageMagick;

MagickImage image = new MagickImage(MagickColors.White, 80, 96);
image.Settings.AntiAlias = false;
image.Settings.StrokeAntiAlias = false;
image.Settings.TextAntiAlias = false;
image.Format = MagickFormat.Png;

var drawables = new Drawables()
            .FillColor(MagickColors.Black)
            .Font("Arial")
            .FontPointSize(14);

drawables.Text(0, 25, "dddDDDddDDWwwWW");
image.Draw(drawables);

image.Write(@"test.png");
```

But the rendering isn't good - it returns different images for the same letter.
Given this example:

[image]

As you can see, 'd' is rendered differently on multiple occasions. How can I improve this?

Comment: **Exactly** which Magick.NET package are you using? You'll get different results between the Q16 vs Q8 builds, for example - and I often get nondeterministic output when I use OpenGL-acceleration.

Comment: I'm using Q8 build now, but same results with Q16

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use monospaced font. E.g. in Windows there are builtin 'Consolas' and 'Courier New' monospaced fonts:

```
var drawables = new Drawables()
        .FillColor(MagickColors.Black)
        .Font("Consolas")
        .FontPointSize(14);
```

Enabling text antialiasing by `TextAntialias(true)` should smooth the text:

```
var drawables = new Drawables()
        .FillColor(MagickColors.Black)
        .Font("Arial")
        .TextAntialias(true)
        .FontPointSize(14);
```

Comment: Antialiasing is turned off because we want sharp text. And even with antialiasing turned on, it still produces various results....

Comment: @Lennart- , then may be consider to use a monospaced font, i've updated my answer